# I want to count (measure) Jargon and Abbreviation Link in HTML web page using java programming language

Tags: java, javascript, dom

May I want to know that how can we count  Jargon text link which is a user unfamiliar word (eg, UNHCR,USR , etc.) in web page . And also want to know how to check and count the abbreviation words (undefined acronyms) in web page. I would like to count jargon and abbreviation words in html web pageusing automated tool  . Thank you.

Comment: Get a list of all abbreviations from http://www.abbreviations.com/ and loop through your HTML page and check for each word.

Comment: You're asking for a complete solution.  That's not going to go over very well.  Perhaps you could think of some more specific questions after you've made a try at a solution and gotten stuck at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java SAXParser API (XML parser)to parse the Html web page. Parse thru the page using SAXParser and for each node that you want to check, parse using Java string parser (which should be quite simple enough). For example you want to want to count the number of links in a page you can find all the  nodes in Html page using XML parser and then check the text value of these  nodes for jargon or abbreviation words.

Hope this helps.